# Django FlatPages vs Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-flatpages, django-cms

Without going into too much detail, I'm building a Django site and I wanted to implement a CMS solution, while having a lot of flexibility with page layouts, navigation, and organization.

It'd be mainly used for our documentation, and so far I've had a lot of headaches trying to figure out the ins-and-outs of Django CMS.

Would an experienced Django developer recommend I use flat-pages with like tiny_mce instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of the 'check 404 then return result' methods of flat-pages, but http://www.punteney.com/writes/django-simplepages-basic-page-cms-system/ might give you just enough power for flat-pages to work in this scenario, without using a full-blown Django CMS.

My approach is generally 'build it *just* big enough' unless something out of the box meets *all* feature requirement, your mileage may vary.

Sounds like essentially you're after a wiki?

Answer (score 7):

You could also take a look at the [CMS apps comparison](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CMSAppsComparison) in the Django wiki and maybe even contribute any missing information.

I've heard good things about [FeinCMS](http://spinlock.ch/pub/feincms/).

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much all the Django CMS(s) out there are born out of the necessity and requirements of the primary developers during a project or two. Most of them do too much, some do too little.
If you are trying to build a CMS so you could dynamically use create content and layout of a site which could be internal or external, you may find yourself confused jumping from one cms to another in the hope of finding the perfect one. Or you can just use mptt or django-categories to give you navigation and nested links. combine that with tiny_mce enabled flat-pages and there you'd have a simple cms that satisfies your requirements. Then you can go and add other stuff if you need to. But if you insist, then try djnago-pages-cms &/or mezzanine which do what you are looking for, but you'd be locked in to use them and build around them.